# How to fix 'dtp.setDate' error in Meteor AutoForm datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, datetimepicker, meteor-autoform

I'm trying to use this AutoForm package, but as I was trying their own code this error came out.

```
TypeError: dtp.setDate is not a function
at null.<anonymous> (aldeed_autoform-bs-datetimepicker.js:141)
at view.js:199
at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (template.js:457)
at view.js:197
at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (view.js:538)
at viewAutorun (view.js:196)
at Tracker.Computation._compute (tracker.js:323)
at new Tracker.Computation (tracker.js:211)
at Object.Tracker.autorun (tracker.js:562)
at Blaze.View.autorun (view.js:209)
```

What I have is, a template just displaying the quick form:

```
<template name="test">
<h1>Autoform test</h1>
{{> quickForm collection="Tests" id="insertTest" type="insert"}}
</template>
```

With a simple schema test also:

```
Tests = new Mongo.Collection("tests");

TestsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  typeTest: {
    type: Date,
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
      afFieldInput: {
        type: "bootstrap-datetimepicker"
      }
    }
  }
});

Tests.attachSchema(TestsSchema);
```

I've followed the instructions given at [this page](http://autoform.meteor.com/types), and added `aldeed:autoform-bs-datetimepicker` and `tsega:bootstrap3-datetimepicker` to my Meteor project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform-bs-datetimepicker/issues/12) in the 4.x.x release. You can fix this error by downgrading to version 3.1.3_3.

To install the **[`tsega:bootstrap3-datetimepicker`](https://atmospherejs.com/tsega/bootstrap3-datetimepicker)** package with version 3.1.3_3, run the following command:

```
meteor add tsega:bootstrap3-datetimepicker@=3.1.3_3
```

You probably also want to install the **[`twbs:bootstrap`](https://atmospherejs.com/twbs/bootstrap)** package in order to get full Bootstrap support.

Comment: This breaks the datetimepicker's css badly.

Comment: @LeQs Really? Which version do you use?

Comment: Just downgraded to 3.1.3_3

Comment: @LeQs Ok and do you use the **[`twbs:bootstrap`](https://atmospherejs.com/twbs/bootstrap)** package?

Comment: Yes i do the twbs:bootstrap.

Comment: @LeQs Ok. You may want to open a separate question, describing your issue in more detail and including a reference to this question.

Comment: I managed to fix the issue. If he widget is not long enough as was in my case,just override the widget width `.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget{
    width:300px !important;
}`